# vuejs 3 data options property no more reactive with external object

Tags: vue.js

I have an app that shares an external module with other applications by sharing a global javascript object.

One of these apps is developed with vue 2 and when the global object is updated in the external module, the option data property of vue 2 is updated perfectly while in vue 3 it is not. I also tried with the new reactive property but nothing to do, is it a bug?

Not being able to make any changes to the external module because it is shared with other apps, how can I make it work in vue 3?

Here are some test links:

[Vue 2 share external object](https://jsfiddle.net/nv7p0srx/)

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script>
var EXTERNAL_OBJECT={
    name:"Bob",
    list:[{name:"Ivan"}]
}

function change_object(){
    EXTERNAL_OBJECT.name+="+++"
    EXTERNAL_OBJECT.list.push({name:"Carl"})
    

}
</script>

<button onClick="change_object()">change external object</button>

<div id="app">

  <div>
  {{share.name}}
  </div>
  <div v-for="item in share.list">
   {{item.name}}
  </div>
</div>

<script>
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    share:EXTERNAL_OBJECT
  }
})
</script>
```

[Vue 3 share external object](https://jsfiddle.net/5Lv0jprq/)

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.2.4/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
<script>
var EXTERNAL_OBJECT={
    name:"Bob",
    list:[{name:"Ivan"}]
}

function change_object(){
    EXTERNAL_OBJECT.name+="+++"
    EXTERNAL_OBJECT.list.push({name:"Carl"})
    

}
</script>

<button onClick="change_object()">change external object</button>

<div id="app">

  <div>
  {{share.name}}
  </div>
  <div v-for="item in share.list">
   {{item.name}}
  </div>
</div>

<script>
const app = Vue.createApp({
  data () {
    return {
      share:EXTERNAL_OBJECT
    }
  }
  
});
app.mount('#app')
</script>
```

[Vue 3 share external object with reactive property](https://jsfiddle.net/0cbzqegd/12/)

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.2.4/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
<script>
var EXTERNAL_OBJECT={
    name:"Bob",
    list:[{name:"Ivan"}]
}

function change_object(){
    EXTERNAL_OBJECT.name+="+++"
    EXTERNAL_OBJECT.list.push({name:"Carl"})
}
</script>

<button onClick="change_object()">change external object</button>

<div id="app">

  <div>
  {{share.name}}
  </div>
  <div v-for="item in share.list">
   {{item.name}}
  </div>
 
</div>
<script>
const { createApp, reactive } = Vue
const app = createApp({
setup(){
 let share = reactive(EXTERNAL_OBJECT)
  return {
  share
  }
},
  data () {
    return {
    msg:"reactive test"
    }
  }
  
});
app.mount('#app')
</script>
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit hard to read ... I just look at the Vue3 Example.
How many file are you showing?

Cant write your EXTERNAL_OBJECT directly in the reactive property? Like:

```
const EXTERNAL_OBJECT = reactive({ name:"Bob",
    list:[{name:"Ivan"}] });
```

Comment: I cannot modify the external module because it is shared with other apps. if you click on title like "Vue 2 share external object"  https://jsfiddle.net/nv7p0srx/  can go on jsfiddle

Comment: 3 jsfiddle link :  Vue 2 share external object (https://jsfiddle.net/nv7p0srx/) ,  Vue 3 share external object (https://jsfiddle.net/5Lv0jprq/) ,  Vue 3 share external object with reactive property (https://jsfiddle.net/0cbzqegd/12/)